# Share image to Gmail app fails with Broken pipe

Tags: android

I want let my user share an image. The image is generated on the fly to `byte[]`. I do not want to write it to a file on external storage, as this will require additional permission.

The problem is, that sharing to Facebook, Twitter or Google Drive works, but sharing to Gmail does not. It fails with:

```
    java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:502)
       at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186)
       at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
       at sk.kios.scorabble.sharing.MediaContentProvider$TransferThread.run(MediaContentProvider.java:79)
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
       at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
       at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:223)
       at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:313)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:497)
       at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186) 
       at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82) 
       at sk.kios.scorabble.sharing.MediaContentProvider$TransferThread.run(MediaContentProvider.java:79)
```

The Gmail app reports "Cannot attach empty file". Am I doing something wrong? This is for the first time I'm doing this.

This is how I send the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content://" + MediaContentProvider.AUTHORITY + "/1"));
intent.setType("image/png");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This is `openFile` method from my `ContentProvider`:

```
@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
    byte data[] = myMethodToCreateImage();

    try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor[] pipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
        new TransferThread(data, new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream(pipe[1]))
            .start();

        return pipe[0];
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not open pipe", e);
    }
}
```

This is the `TransferThread` class:

```
static class TransferThread extends Thread {
    private final byte[] data;
    private final OutputStream out;

    TransferThread(byte[] data, OutputStream out) {
        this.data = data;
        this.out = out;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            out.write(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception transferring file", e);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I initially thought it is a bug of gmail, see here: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3141. But this bug is related only to android 6 marshmallow, which is not my case.

It turned out that it works better if you set the uri not as `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM`, but with `intent.setDataAndType`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://" + MediaContentProvider.AUTHORITY + "/1"), "image/png");
context.startActivity(intent);
```